# OverridePendingTransition with the current activity on top

Tags: android, animation, android-intent

I want the current `ScoreActivity.this` to slide up and the `GameActivity.class` to stay in place in the background.

It works great going from the `GameActivity` to the `ScoreActivity`, but on the way back it just shows the `GameActivity` without animation. (Because the slide_up happens behind it I'm assuming)

Anything helps, including pointing me to a good duplicate post.

**ScoreActivity**

```
restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, GameActivity.class);

        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT); Neither of these work
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change, R.anim.slide_up);
    }
});
```

**GameActivity** (Triggered when user gets a "game over")

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_down, R.anim.no_change);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define zAdjustment on both animations xml's.

On first - android:zAdjustment="bottom"

On Second - android:zAdjustment="top"

Comment: The ScoreActivity is where animations don't work. 

GameActivity animations work great.

Comment: 1.Do you want the animation to be triggered onBackPressed?

2.Use 0 instead of "R.anim.no_change"

Comment: The animation is triggered in an onClick as shown in the question.

Comment: It has been added. 0 does not work for either as well

Comment: Btw, did u try using zAdjustment in your anim xml?

Comment: No, I've also never heard of it. Example?

Comment: in your anim xml: android:zAdjustment="bottom" and the second one is top

Comment: That was it! Change up your answer and I'll accept it!